Using "thereof" properly

...It is also clear that the contingent migrant workforce in the US was highest in number, but the ratio per 1000 population thereof was lowest in 2006.

According to the OALD, thereof means of the thing mentioned. Here, the bolded part I wrote above was meant to refer to the ratio of the contingent migrant workforce in the US per 1000 population.
Thereof is formal and it's an advanced word to my mind. I'm trying to learn how to use it properly since it seems useful in shortening phrases. Could you tell me if my logic above is correct?


If "thereof" means of the total U.S.population, I think it would be clearer as "per 1000 U.S. population." That is partly because the sentence seems to be comparing ""contingent migrant workforce" to some other groups  ("highest"). You might need to quote more of the preceding sentences.

I would say that thereof is too formal and old-fashioned to use in an article about statistics.

@JackO'Flaherty I think you mightn't have seen the table. The sentence talked about the numbers shown in it.

@KateBunting It's an IELTS essay, not an article, so I don't think I would have to care about being overly formal.

@JackO'Flaherty thereof = of the contingent migrant workforce in the US here. It was what I meant.

@KenAdams  The sentence should be clear without the table. You may be pushing too much into too few sentences. In any case, we usually look at existing texts, rather than evaluating student compositions.

@JackO'Flaherty I agree that the sentence should be clear without the table. Maybe the reason why you misunderstood the sentence is that I didn't include the whole passage. I'll write it down to see if you find the use of "thereof" any clearer here.

The table illustrates how many temporary migrant employees there were in four different nations in 2003 and 2006 and also depicts the rate of them in the latter year.
Overall, there was an increase in the number of migrants who worked temporarily in all countries examined. It is also clear that temporary worker numbers in the US were highest, but the ratio per 1000 people thereof was lowest in 2006.
